# how to filter foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Hello their i have two table one is **StudentData** and other is **Enrollment**. Below are the codes for them

```
class StudentData(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name        = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=1)
    department          = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program             = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_admitted         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_closed         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentData,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(TeachingSemester,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When student logins , the website shows data according to **logged user** , below is the code

```
log_user = request.user
student_information = StudentData.objects.filter(user=log_user)
```

What can i do so that the **Enrollment** of only **logged in** is shown on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter by student:

```
log_user = request.user
student_information = StudentData.objects.filter(user=log_user)

enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(student=student_information)
```

If you prefer to get `Enrollment`s by user you can also do:

```
log_user = request.user
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(student__user=log_user)
```